# How do I create a shortcut for a script, and run it as a .desktop file?

Tags: ubuntu, symlink

I have installed Teamspeak onto my Ubuntu 15.10 system. Teamspeak requires a script to be ran in-order to start. How can I create a symbolic link that is a .desktop so I can open the .desktop file, and have it run the script? I have looked at a few methods, but they all seem like hotfixes. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: This has some good answers: http://askubuntu.com/q/64222/47291

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`, add something like the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Teamspeak
Comment=Teamspeak
Exec=/path/to/teamspeak.sh
Icon=/path/to/teamspeak-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

This is included in the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602091/teamspeak-3-on-ubuntu). I recomend you read them, but you may want to move the files to a 'hidden' location like `~/.teamspeak-install` instead  `/opt`

Comment: This is perfect! I saw a few other methods, but it just seems slightly odd. I guess that's linux for ya.

Comment: Not always. There were a few apps that allowed you create custom launchers (still are for Xfce etc I think). If this helped you can accept it using the tick mark next to the answer :)